# Bash While loop for user input and error prompt with a counter for max tries

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I have a while loop created to take user input and repeat the prompt in case of an error.

```
while true; do
        read -p "Enter hostname : " fqdn
        pattern="(^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$)"
        
        if [[ -z "$fqdn" ]]; then   #if fqdn input is empty
                echo "Error! Hostname cannot be empty"
                continue
        elif [[ ! "${fqdn}" =~ ${pattern} ]]; then
                echo "Error! Format incorrect"
                continue
        else
                echo "hostname is $fqdn"
                break
        fi
done
```

**My goal:**

1. In case of ***if/elif*** statement how to show the prompt only twice and
   then exit.
2. Is there a way, the above while loop can be improved, e.g. using a
   ***case switch***. I find case switch difficult to comprehend?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 (headless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative at the top of my mind, I'm sure it can be improved:

```bsh
# declare the pattern outside the loop
pattern="(^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$)"
# declare a counter for failed attempts
c=0

while true; do
  # if counter is equal to 2 exit
  [[ $c -eq 2 ]] && echo "Two failed attempts. Exiting" && exit

  read -p "Enter hostname : " fqdn

  if [[ -z "$fqdn" ]]; then
    echo "Error! Hostname cannot be empty"
    ((c++)) # increment the counter
    continue
  elif [[ ! "${fqdn}" =~ ${pattern} ]]; then
    echo "Error! Format incorrect"
    ((c++)) # increment the counter
    continue
  fi
  
  # this lines will be executed only if the conditions passed
  echo "hostname is $fqdn"
  break
done
```

The `case` constructs don't use regular expressions, so for complex matching it's better to use `if elif..` statements.

Comment: thnx! as for the 1st question, how to add a counter to the if/else statement so that they are broken after two attempts individually i.e. when if/elif statement is hit twice it will exit the script

Comment: @depar let me see, I hope I understand you.

Comment: that was pure gold!! `[[ $c -eq 2 ]] && echo "Two failed attempts. Exiting" && exit` this I never imagined.

Answer (score 2):

The following `bash` script reads a string from the user and tests whether the string fulfills the criteria for a hostname that you seem to want to enforce.

The first of the two patterns used in the `case` statement tests for the pathological case of two dots with no characters in-between (this is a pattern that we don't act upon).  We test for a string containing at least two dots and no dot at either end with the second pattern.  The hostname variable `fdqn` is set to the string only if this second pattern matches the string.  Note that the string `foo..bar` matches the second pattern, which is why we preemptively match the double dot substring with the first pattern.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

unset -v count fdqn

while true; do
        read -p 'Enter hostname: ' -r

        case $REPLY in (*..*) ;; ([!.]*.*.*[!.]) fdqn=$REPLY; break; esac

        echo 'Invalid format' >&2

        count=$(( count + 1 ))
        [ "$count" -eq 2 ] && break
done

if [ -z "$fdqn" ]; then
        echo 'No valid hostname entered' >&2
        exit 1
fi

printf 'The hostname is "%s"\n' "$fdqn"
```

The `count` variable keeps track of how many times the user has tried to enter a string.  We break out of the loop if this variable's value reaches two.

There is no real need to use a `case` statement here unless you want to make it a portable `sh` script (in which case you would have to do the `read` statement differently).  With the globbing operator `==` in `bash`, the `case` statement would be written like below.

```bsh
if [[ $REPLY == *..* ]]; then
        :
elif [[ $REPLY == [!.]*.*.*[!.] ]]; then
        fdqn=$REPLY
        break
fi
```

The two tests could also be joined using `&&` if the first is negated.

```bsh
if [[ $REPLY != *..* ]] && [[ $REPLY == [!.]*.*.*[!.] ]]; then
        fdqn=$REPLY
        break
fi
```

If you want to avoid getting hostnames containing three dots, then make sure that `$REPLY` does not match `*.*.*.*`, just like it shouldn't match `*..*`.